# Chrome issue - keyring - workaround found but how to fix?

Tags: google-chrome

I am running Ubuntu and a few days ago I started having problems with Chrome.
The process would start but the window would not open.

Googling around I found this workaround:

Kill all the chrome processes and then run:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
```

In the terminal, authentication will be needed and voila! Chrome is opening again.

Of course, I don't understand how and why and I don't know how to permanently fix the problem.
Now every time I reboot I have to run the command from the terminal and then open chrome.

Sorry for the stupid question, any hint appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered re-installing?

Comment: re-installing chrome you mean?

Comment: Are you using the gnome desktop

Comment: Do you have the package `dbus-user-session` installed?

Comment: @dobey no I don't

Comment: @george I am using kde

Comment: OK. I had a similar problem with chromium, and recently discovered dbus-user-session was installed, which broke keyring related stuff, causing chromium to hang.